What is causing black staining on white plastic in my new home?
6 months ago we purchased our first house, a new build.  In the first few months, we noticed this black staining to many smooth surfaces including all the white plastic in the house - from the white washer and dryer to light switch plates to even the refrigerator water filter.  It does not come off easily (we used brightneasy for partial improvement) and doesn't appear like mold.
The cabinets were flush with the microwave (i.e. the vent was mostly covered by the cabinet), so we have fixed that.  When we removed the cabinet above the microwave, the wall behind the cabinet above the microwave was also covered in this black staining.  I have also changed our the air filters.  Has anyone seen this before?

Seems like a clear photo is required here for anyone to help. We're guessing, otherwise.

Are any of the occupants smokers?

Can you describe the black substance better? Is it dry, wet, oily, paint-like, etc? What cleaning products have you tried? Is this only found on plastic surfaces? Is this substance found elsewhere besides the kitchen? Did the air filters have the stuff? Could this be residue or soot from cooking?
